# Searching for all the array elements in another array?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

This is how I would search for an element in an array.

```
count=${#ARRAY[@]}

lsearch()
{
  status=-1

  for((i=0;i<count;i++))
  do
     Temp=$1

     if [[ $Temp -eq ${ARRAY[i]} ]]
       then
         status=0
         searches=$((i+1))
         return
     fi
   done
}
```

Suppose I need to look for all the elements of an array say `(a b c d)` in another array `( a h c d l k)`.

Now for each element in one array I need to loop over the other array with a for loop.
Is there any better way?

Comment: Do you need to look up values frequently? If so, you could create an associative array with the reversed key-value pairs of the second array. http://pastebin.com/TDuG4Av8

Comment: Are there constraints on the array elements, or can they be arbitrary strings?

Comment: they can be arbitrary strings but unique

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to loop through each entry of the second array for each value in the first, then you'll need to use an associative array. In awk you could do this:

```bash
$ a=(a b c d);
$ b=(a h c d l k);
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS = FS} NR == FNR {a[$1] = 1; next} $1 in a' \
    <(echo "${a[*]}") <(echo "${b[*]}")
a
c
d
```

Pure bash would look something like this (although it is a little unwieldy.:

```bash
declare -A a
a=([a]=1 [b]=1 [c]=1 [d]=1)
declare -A b
b=([a]=1 [h]=1 [c]=1 [d]=1 [l]=1 [k]=1)
for i in ${!a[*]}; do
    if [ ! -z "${b[$i]}" ]; then 
        echo "$i is in both";
    fi;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash that does not loop through every item in the second array and is also not quite so "unwieldy" as [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124648/285492).

```bsh
a=(a b c d);
b=(a h c d l k);

newArr=($(
    for item in ${a[@]}; do
        [[ ${b[*]} =~ (^|[[:space:]])"$item"($|[[:space:]]) ]] \
        && echo "$item"
    done    
))
```

```bsh
echo ${newArr[@]}

a c d
```

```
echo ${!newArr[@]}

0 1 2
```

Could also make a new array from items in first array *not* in the second array.  Simply change the `&&` to `||`.

```bsh
newArr=($(
    for item in ${a[@]}; do
        [[ ${b[*]} =~ (^|[[:space:]])"$item"($|[[:space:]]) ]] \
        || echo "$item"
    done    
))
```

```bsh
echo ${newArr[@]}

b
```